# I happen to have been or I happened to have been?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> I happen**ed** to have been working for this company for 11 years.
>
> I happen to have been working for this company for 11 years.

I think the second option is more logical as it's about the present, isn't it? But nevertheless I saw the first option in a textbook and it might be a mistake (as there were others).

I happen to have been or I happened to have been?

Comment: It is just a matter of tense(s).

Comment: Logic is a very poor guide to resolve questions of language.

Answer (score 2):

As @Ram Pillai said in a comment above - it's simply a different verb tense.

> I happened to have been working for this company for 11 years.

means "**At the time I am speaking of**, I happened to have been working..." -
this is the past progressive tense.

> I happen to have been working for this company for 11 years.

means "**As of right now**, I happen to have been working..." -
this is the present progressive tense.

In the first case, it is possible that the speaker does not currently work for the company.   In the second case, it is not.